# Youtube url iframe problems

Tags: php, html, string, iframe, youtube

I am trying to load a **youtube** IFrame using a string from my php, I know the string is getting the videos url but when put into the html the video will not load.

Methods I have tried. The URL is the full youtube URL no shortened.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?=$purl?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?=$_SESSION['theurl']?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?$purl?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Maybe Im doing it wrong? Also I tried the old object method with the same failed results.

Comment: How's $url? just a regular youtube url?

Comment: And the URL you're including is...?

Comment: What are the values of `$purl` and `$_SESSION['theurl']`? The third way won't work because you aren't actually echoing anything by only using `<? ?>`, so you can ignore that.

Comment: Are short tags allowed by your host? `<?php echo $purl;?>` doesn't work either?

Comment: short tags work fine on everything else, i know the data is in $purl as when I echo it alone it posts.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML it produces?

Comment: Upon view source it produces `code`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB95KLmpLR4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`code`

Comment: @damien <?php echo $purl;?> = same result

Comment: @Will, prepend the http:// part

Answer (score 0):

Your youtube link should look like this if you want to set is as an iframe src:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/bFXb9F

Comment: Great so now I have to write a parser, thanks youtube. Thank you sir

Comment: @WillBlew you don't need a parse, why not just embedding the code they provide?